# How do I check if the user input is an integer

Tags: python, input, integer, character, sequence

I wanted to make a code where if the user entered any invalid options out of the menu displayed, it would ask the user to enter a valid option, which in this case is the integers 1-7.

But here no matter what options the user enters, it will display that it is an invalid choice.

```
def update_profile():
        while True:
            print("Choose the options below to update the info")
            print("1.Username\n2.Password\n3.Email\n4.Date of Birth\n5.Address\n6.Contact Number\n7.Exit")
            choice = input("Enter your choice:")

            try:
                int(choice)
            except ValueError:
                pass

            match choice:
                case 1:
                   ...
                case 2:
                   ...
                case _:
                   print("Invalid choice. Please select again.")
                   print("--------------------------------------------")
                   continue
            repeat = input("Do you want to continue update the profile? <Yes [Y]\tNo [N]>\nYour choice: ")
            if repeat == 'N' or repeat == 'n':
                break
```

OUTPUT:

```
Choose the options below to update the info
1.Username
2.Password
3.Email
4.Date of Birth
5.Address
6.Contact Number
7.Exit
Enter your choice:1
Invalid choice. Please select again.
--------------------------------------------
Choose the options below to update the info
1.Username
2.Password
3.Email
4.Date of Birth
5.Address
6.Contact Number
7.Exit
Enter your choice:
```

Comment: `int(choice)` doesn't change `choice`. It gives back an integer but you ignore the returned value. You need `choice = int(choice)`.

Comment: Why not just use the options as strings? There's no need for them to be converted to integer

Answer (score 0):

int() doesn't change its arguments value, it returns the result.
So within the exception handling block you might assign a  a new variable and use it for the match block.

```
def update_profile():
while True:
    print("Choose the options below to update the info")
    print("1.Username\n2.Password\n3.Email\n4.Date of Birth\n5.Address\n6.Contact Number\n7.Exit")
    choice = input("Enter your choice:")
    try:
        choice_int = int(choice)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
        pass

    match choice_int:
        case 1:
            ...
        case 2:
            ...
        case _:
            print("Invalid choice. Please select again.")
            print("--------------------------------------------")
            continue
    repeat = input("Do you want to continue update the profile? <Yes [Y]\tNo [N]>\nYour choice: ")
    if repeat == 'N' or repeat == 'n':
        break
```